# php soap call without xsi:type

Tags: php, soap-client, xsitype

I am using php soap to make calls to a web service but the operator of the service wants us to switch to non-wsdl mode so it doesn't need to be exposed. I get bad requests and looking at the request generated I notice one main difference between the requests going out.

```
<ns1:userpwd>password</ns1:userpwd>
```

vs.

```
<ns1:userpwd xsi:type="xsd:string">password</ns1:userpwd>
```

All the parameters have this additional xsi:type="xsd:string" Currently I am using

```
new SoapParam($password, "ns1:userPWD");
```

to generate the parameters. What do I need to do different to omit the xsi:type attribute from the xml for the call that eventually gets sent out?

Answer (score 0):

Once again thinking the question through enough to write it up points to an answer:

new SoapVar("$password", XSD_ANYXML); produces the desired result in the request